# How do I center text within span?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an issue. I can't center the text within the `<span>` tag. I do understand that I would need to switch the `<span>` tag to a `<div>` or `<p>` tag I believe? However, when I tried this, the whole functionality of the button failed.

I'll paste the entire code below, take a look and see if you can help me.

Thanks.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
#more {display: none;}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<span id="dots"></span><span id="more">erisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta.</span></p>
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">Read more</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
  var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
  var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read more"; 
    moreText.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read less"; 
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's presently a little unclear what you're asking. Centering text in a span has no obvious relationship with the functionality of a button. Please clarify.

Comment: What do you want to center, the **button** or the **resulting text**?

Comment: Do you want to center or to justify the text?

Comment: When you click the "Read more" button, I want the text that appears to be centered. I've read on here that doing so, I would need to change the tags before the text to a "div" tag, but upon doing so, the button no longer works. If you try it out yourself you'll see what I mean. I'm not too knowledgeable when it comes to coding but I tried to replace the "span" tags with "div" tags and entered the center text command code, but the button no longer works after doing so. I can't explain it really, just seems that it's somehow interrupted when I replaced the "span" tags with "div" tags.

Comment: I'd like to center the text. Now that you mention it, centering the button also would be nice as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use display block instead of inline if you want to use span otherwise you can switch to `p` or `div` tag

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
#more {display: none;}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<span id="dots"></span><span id="more">erisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta.</span></p>
   <div style="text-align:center"> <button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">Read more</button></div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
  var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
  var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read more"; 
    moreText.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read less"; 
    moreText.style.display = "block";
   moreText.style.textAlign = "center";
 //  btnText.parentElement.style.textAlign = "center";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like this did the trick, thank you! Another commentator asked if I wanted the button centered also, and I think that would look good. Would you know how to center the button as well?

Comment: updated my answer. You need to wrap your button inside div and then just center that div on button click

Comment: Is there a way to center the button before clicking on it also? Thank you for helping out.

Comment: That's more simpler. Just give inline style to div. Check my answer now

Comment: This is exactly how I wanted it! Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate you taking your time to help me out, been looking for the solution all night. Glad I made this account.

Comment: happy to help :)

Comment: I know you just did a lot for me, I had one more question regarding this and since your active at the moment I might as well ask, if I wanted to space some of the sentences within the text, how would I accomplish this? I thought pressing the "Enter tab" would space it out but for some reason it wont space out? Maybe you know how to fix this? Thanks :)

Comment: To add space between the sentences use `&nbsp;` 1 for 1 space. If you want to break the sentence use `<br />`

Comment: Actually never mind, I was able to figure it out. I used the "</br>" tags in-between the sentences I wanted separated from each-other. I didn't think I'd be able to that, but it worked. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Looks like we had the same solution haha. Yeah thank you Arun, I know who to come to for button issues :D

Comment: Hey Arun, I added this to my website and it works fine on desktop but for some reason it stopped functioning on mobile? The button will appear but it won't do anything when you try to click on it? I'm not sure why it stopped working as it was working fine last night. Any thoughts?

Comment: try to debug your javascript code for mobile using chrome emulator and see if there are any erros

Answer (score 0):

You just add a div around your existing tags:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
#more {display: none;}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div style="margin: 12px 0 3px; text-align: center;">
<span id="dots"></span><span id="more">erisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta.</span></p>
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">Read more</button>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
  var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
  var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read more";
    moreText.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read less";
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure either JavaScript is about to.
Basically the answer how do i center my HTML content is by using CSS.
This could be done using the style(prefer external files if not for testing and debug) attribute `text-align:center;`
Difference in div and span are semantic of course(one for ext content, other one for an unknow DIVide part of page -that is yet to avoid in HTML5 using section, article or any of more descriptive tag). Difference is also that div have default style rule display:block when default span display attribute is inline.
Neither will change JavaScript because in file STYLE tag there a display:none; then in the click binded function (MyFunction() ) you have this:

```
  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
```

Meaning a 'switch' who'll set inline or none to the display value depending the current value(before the function run) set of this display. So what about changing a span to div? It's useless and if your span content is some text put it to a div will be lesser accurate; think SEO.